# JSON convert Map with Integer keys

Tags: java, json, dictionary, integer, converters

I have a small sample of test code where I try to convert a Map into a JSON string  and back. While parsing from the JSON string, the resulting map contains the String key "1" instead of the Integer key "1", thus making the test fail. The same happens with POJOs used as the key to this map. Is this behaviour expected or have I ommited some configuration for the JSON converters?

```
public class SampleConverterTest {

   @Test
   public void testIntegerKey() {

      // Register an Integer converter
      JSON.registerConvertor(Integer.class, new JSONPojoConvertor(Integer.class));

      Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
      map.put(1, "sample");
      // Convert to JSON
      String msg = JSON.toString(map);
      // Retrieve original map from JSON
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      Map<Integer, String> obj = (Map<Integer, String>) JSON.parse(msg);

      assertTrue(obj.containsKey(1));
   }
}
```

I am using jetty-util 7.6.10.v20130312

Comment: JSON keys are strings, by definition.

Comment: JSON keys are [strings](http://www.json.org/)

Some JSON parsers will accept non standard JSON, which could include non string keys, but its best to stick to the standard

Comment: That means then that no POJOs can be used as keys as well, correct?
In the case of using Sample.class as a key I would expect that the key is translated into a JSON string such as {"class":"test.test.Sample","id":1} but that does not happen in the case of Map --> JSON string.

Comment: For most JSON libraries, Map is the default implementation that the parser converts the JSON into.  Therefore, the class is not specified when generating JSON from a map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like @HotLicks said, when you convert objects to JSON, the key part of the JSON map will be returned as a String.  I don't believe there's any way to move around this behavior.  I'd also steer clear of using integers as keys in your map, if the intended behavior is as a JSON map.  Instead, I'd do something like:

```
map.put("identifier", 1);
map.put("value", "sample");
```

It's a little bit more verbose, but it's also easier to see how that translates to JSON.

Comment: Thanks Jason and the other guys for clarifying what the JSON can support and what not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `map<int,int>` is not matched properly. It is possible to use a derived class - like so:

```
struct Int_int_map : map<int, int> {

    inline friend void to_json(json &j, Int_int_map const &m) {
        j = json();
        for (auto &key_val : m)
            j[to_string(key_val.first)] = key_val.second;
    }

    inline friend void from_json(const json &j, Int_int_map &m) {
        for (auto &key_val : j.get<json::object_t>()) 
            m[std::stoi(key_val.first)] = key_val.second;       
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The map can also be stored as an array of tuples/pairs.

```
{
  "myMap" : [
    {"key": 1, "value": 42}, 
    {"key": 2, "value": 21}, 
    {"key": 3, "value": 31415}
  ]
}
```